# Linker Errors LNK2019/LNK2001 after splitting up my code into multiple files/using global variables

Tags: c++, global-variables, linker-errors

I have started to write some code for a vulkan application and after a while I have splitted up my code in multiple files for example a File full of the most important global Variables.After that I got a lot of errors with included files but I was able to fix these.... I think. But after that there were many linker errors with my global variables and some functions and I have tried many thinks but nothing helped very much. Here are some Files of my Project:

Main.cpp:

```
 #ifndef Security_V_StartUpInc
#define Security_V_StartUpInc
#include "Vulkan_Startup.h"
#endif // !Security_V.StartUpInc
int main() {
     
    VulkanUtility::main_Start_Vulkan__();
__Pause;
    return 0;
     
}
```

Vulkan_Startup.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Security_VulkanLibInc
#define Security_VulkanLibInc
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#endif // !Security_VulkanLibInc

#ifndef Security_StructVarinc
#define Security_StructVarinc
#include "StructVariables.h"
#endif // !Security_StructVarinc

#ifndef Security_VariblesInc
#define Security_VariblesInc
#include "Variables.h"
#endif // !Security_VariblesInc




#define SpecSecure(var)\
if(var==2){Variables::Global::Err.PrinttoLog(12,Variables::Global::Errorregister);return 2;}
#define Advancedsecure(var) \
if(var==2){Variables::Global::Err.PrinttoLog(11,Variables::Global::Errorregister);return 1;}

namespace VulkanUtility {


     inline void printLog(int result, int Stat);
     inline void printLog(VkResult result, int Stat);
           inline  int InitVulkan__();
          inline    int main_Start_Vulkan__();
}
```

Vulkan_Startup.cpp

```
 
#include "Vulkan_Startup.h"
 



 
 
 
 
 

    inline void VulkanUtility::printLog(int result, int Stat) {
        if (result != 0) {
            Variables::Global::Err.PrinttoLog(Stat * 2 - 1, Variables::Global::Errorregister);
        }
        else {
            Variables::Global::Err.PrinttoLog(Stat * 2, Variables::Global::Errorregister);
        }
    }
    inline void  VulkanUtility::printLog(VkResult result, int Stat) {
        if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
            Variables::Global::Err.PrinttoLog(Stat * 2 - 1, Variables::Global::Errorregister);
        }
        else {
            Variables::Global::Err.PrinttoLog(Stat * 2, Variables::Global::Errorregister);
        }
    }
    inline    int  VulkanUtility::InitVulkan__() {





        Variables::Global::CP.Number_of_Graphical_Devices = 0;

        Variables::Global::VT.AppInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
        Variables::Global::VT.AppInfo.pNext = NULL;
//...
         return 0;
    }


    inline int VulkanUtility:: main_Start_Vulkan__() {



        InitVulkan__();
        int res;

        VkPhysicalDeviceProperties* PhysicalDeviceProp = nullptr;
        VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures* PhysikalDeviceFeat = nullptr;
        VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties* Memprop;
        VkQueueFamilyProperties* Queue;
        res = Variables::Global::CP.GetProperties(0, PhysicalDeviceProp);
        if (Variables::Global::EnableLog) { printLog(res, 4); Advancedsecure(res) };

        res = Variables::Global::CP.GetFeatures(0, PhysikalDeviceFeat);
        if (Variables::Global::EnableLog) { printLog(res, 5); Advancedsecure(res) };
        res = Variables::Global::CP.GetMemoryProperties(0, Memprop);
        if (Variables::Global::EnableLog) { printLog(res, 7); Advancedsecure(res) };

        res = Variables::Global::CP.getQueueProperties(0, Queue);
        if (Variables::Global::EnableLog) { printLog(res, 8); SpecSecure(res) }

        __Pause;
        return 0;

    }
```

StructVariables.h

```
 #pragma once
#define Security_StructVarinc
#ifndef Security_VulkanLibInc
#define Security_VulkanLibInc
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#endif // !Security_VulkanLibInc
 
#ifndef Security_DefInc
#define Security_DefInc
#include "Define.h"
#endif // !Security_StructVarInc
#ifndef Security_MapVarInc
#define Security_MapVarInc
#include "MapLib.h"
#endif // !Security_StructVarInc


 
#ifndef Security_Errorhandlerinc
#define Security_Errorhandlerinc
#include "Errorhandler.h"
#endif // Security_Errorhandlerinc

 

namespace Variables
{
     
    namespace Predefined_Structs {

        struct Vinstance
        {
            VkApplicationInfo AppInfo;
            VkInstanceCreateInfo InsInfo;
            VkInstance Instance;

        };

        struct ComputerSpecs
        {
            uint32_t* Queuecount;
            uint32_t  Number_of_Graphical_Devices;
            VkPhysicalDevice* Devices;
            VkPhysicalDeviceProperties* Properties;
            VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures* Features;
            VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties* Memprop;
            VkQueueFamilyProperties* Queueprop;
            ComputerSpecs();
            void Set();
            void Advancedset();
            int Setqueue();
            int GetProperties(int devicecount, VkPhysicalDeviceProperties*& Properties);
            int GetFeatures(int devicecount, VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures*& Features);
            int GetMemoryProperties(int Devicecount, VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties*& Memprop);
            int getQueueProperties(int Devicecount, VkQueueFamilyProperties*& Queue);
            ~ComputerSpecs();

        };
        struct Errorreg {
            Allocater::ExclMapLib<String>* Register;
            Errorreg();
            ~Errorreg();

        };

    }
}
```

StructVariables.cpp

```
#include "StructVariables.h"

        Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::ComputerSpecs()
        {
            Number_of_Graphical_Devices = 0;
            Queuecount = nullptr;
            VkPhysicalDevice* Devices = nullptr;
        }

        void Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::Set()
        {
            Devices = new VkPhysicalDevice[Number_of_Graphical_Devices];
            Properties = nullptr;
            Features = nullptr;
            Memprop = nullptr;
            Queueprop = nullptr;
        }

        void Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::Advancedset()
        {
            Properties = new VkPhysicalDeviceProperties[Number_of_Graphical_Devices];
            Features = new VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures[Number_of_Graphical_Devices];
            Memprop = new VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties[Number_of_Graphical_Devices];

            for (int i = 0; i < Number_of_Graphical_Devices; i++) {
                vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(Devices[i], Properties);
                vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(Devices[i], Features);
                vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties(Devices[i], Memprop);
            }
            Setqueue();
        }

        int Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::Setqueue()
        {
            if (Devices != nullptr && Number_of_Graphical_Devices != 0) {

                Queuecount = new uint32_t[Number_of_Graphical_Devices];
                for (int i = 0; i < Number_of_Graphical_Devices; i++) {
                    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(Devices[i], &Queuecount[i], nullptr);
                    Queueprop = new VkQueueFamilyProperties[Queuecount[i]];
                    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(Devices[i], &Queuecount[i], Queueprop);

                }

                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }

        int Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::GetProperties(int devicecount, VkPhysicalDeviceProperties*& Properties)
        {
            if (devicecount >= Number_of_Graphical_Devices) { return 1; }
            else if (this->Properties != nullptr) {
                Properties = this->Properties;
                return 0;
            }
            return 2;
        }

        int Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::GetFeatures(int devicecount, VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures*& Features)
        {
            if (devicecount >= Number_of_Graphical_Devices) { return 1; }
            else if (this->Features != nullptr) {
                Features = this->Features;
                return 0;
            }
            return 2;
        }

        int Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::GetMemoryProperties(int Devicecount, VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties*& Memprop)
        {
            if (Devicecount >= Number_of_Graphical_Devices) { return 1; }
            else if (this->Memprop != nullptr) {
                Memprop = this->Memprop; return 0;
            }
            return 2;
        }

        int Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::getQueueProperties(int Devicecount, VkQueueFamilyProperties*& Queue)
        {
            if (Devicecount >= Number_of_Graphical_Devices) { return 1; }
            else if (this->Queueprop != nullptr) {
                Queue = this->Queueprop; return 0;
            }
            return 2;
        }

        Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs::~ComputerSpecs()
        {
            delete[] Memprop;
            delete[] Features;
            delete[] Properties;
            delete[] Devices;
            delete[] Queuecount;
            delete[] Queueprop;
        }

        Variables::Predefined_Structs::Errorreg::Errorreg()
        {
            Register = new Allocater::ExclMapLib<String>(100);
            Register->CreateShelf(1, "Unable_to_create_Vulkan_Instance");
            Register->CreateShelf(2, "Succesfully created Vulkan Instance");
             //....
        }
         
        Variables::Predefined_Structs::Errorreg::~Errorreg()
        {
            Register->Test();
            delete Register;
        }
```

Variables.h

```
 #pragma once
#ifndef Security_StructVarinc
#define Security_StructVarinc
#include "StructVariables.h"
#endif  
#ifndef Security_Errorhandlerinc
define Security_Errorhandlerinc
#include "Errorhandler.h"
#endif // !Security_Errorhandlerinc


 
namespace Variables {
    namespace Predefined_Structs
    {
        struct Vinstance;
        struct ComputerSpecs;
        struct Errorreg;
    }
}
  
namespace Variables {
    namespace Global
    {
        extern bool EnableLog  ;
        extern Variables::Predefined_Structs::Vinstance VT;
        extern Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs CP;
        extern Variables::Predefined_Structs::Errorreg Errorregister;
        extern Handling::Errorhandler Err;




    }
}
```

...And some other files.

In this Configuration I get the Error:LNK1120,LNK2019-...  ""int **cdecl VulkanUtility::main_Start_Vulkan**(void)" (?main_Start_Vulkan__@VulkanUtility@@YAHXZ)" in Funktion "_main" ;

But if I put the code of the Vulkan_Startup.cpp file inside of the Vulkan_Startup.h(without the "#include"Vulkan_Startup.h"" at the top) file i get these errors: again LNK 1120 but with 5x LNK2001:

1. ...""class Handling::Errorhandler Variables::Global::Err" (?Err@Global@Variables@@3VErrorhandler@Handling@@A)".
2. ...  ""bool Variables::Global::EnableLog"
   (?EnableLog@Global@Variables@@3_NA)".
3. ...  ""struct Variables::Predefined_Structs::ComputerSpecs Variables::Global::CP"
   (?CP@Global@Variables@@3UComputerSpecs@Predefined_Structs@2@A)".
4. ...  ""struct Variables::Predefined_Structs::Errorreg Variables::Global::Errorregister"
   (?Errorregister@Global@Variables@@3UErrorreg@Predefined_Structs@2@A)".
5. ... ""struct Variables::Predefined_Structs::Vinstance Variables::Global::VT" (?VT@Global@Variables@@3UVinstance@Predefined_Structs@2@A)".

Sorry for maybe bad english at some points.
Thanks for your help.

Edit: I have now deleted every global variables and now there arent any LNK 2001 errors-> Every global variables are now functions params and defined in the main file. But there are also the error LNK 2019 in this code : But if I put the definitions of the VulkanStartup.cpp file into the header file everything works fine: But I dont want to put just the definition into the header file because I want to learn what I shouldnt do next time and not to leave this error behind me without learning anything.
Also thanks for your help until this point!

Comment: Try not to use global variables, *ever*. Although occasionally useful/sensible, they usually cause more problems in the long run than they solve (same goes for singletons (which are just glorified global variables after all)).